# Login by multiple user accounts when using JSON Web Token

Tags: authentication, jwt

I am using JSON Web Token to authenticate the user in my application. Using https://jwt.io documentation, I use the jwt token to authenticate the user.

```
$tokenData = array(
    "jti" => $tokenId,
    "iat" => $issuedAt,
    "exp" => $expire,
    "user" => $user
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($tokenData, $secretKey, 'HS512');
```

But the problem is when one user can not login from multiple devices at the same time, it gives an error since the first login token get invaidated. Is there a way to handle this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean first token is invalidated - how?

Comment: when same user login from two different devices or two browsers with the same user account, the first login is invalidated and automatically log out from the system.

Comment: but how? how do you invalidate the JWT?